# Gitlab не отправляется почта

Tags: email, gitlab

Установили Gitlab на debian, работает все кроме почты. С сервера не отправляется почта (в т.ч. для получения пароля на вход) 
Подскажите что может быть.
Настройку почты выполняли так: https://gist.github.com/xavierjurado/3138813

Comment: Перезапускали его после изменений? Логи (`log/production.log`) смотрели?

Comment: а соединиться-то можно с указанным сервером на указанном порту? `telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`

Comment: Спасибо! Настроили вчера уже все.

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.